# Why do I get an error when checking an optional UIView parameter in a generic function?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a generic function in Swift that accepts an optional UIView object that conforms to a specific protocol:

```
    func addViewToPool<T: UIView where T: ViewPoolProtocol>(inout view: T?) {
        if T != nil {
            pool.addObject(T)
        }
    }
```

In the second line I'm trying to make sure the object is not nil. However, I get the warning:

```
Value of type 'T.Type' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed
```

I could unwrap it or add the potentially nil value, but I'm trying to *understand* why this error is happening.

Comment: T means some generic type, not an instance of it. thats, why it can never be nil.  if view != nil { pool.addObject(view) } should works here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check if the view you pass to this function is not `nil` like this

```
if view != nil {
    pool.addObject(view)
}
```

You are checking if a type (`T`) is not nil and this is always true, you got confused between your variable and its type.

Comment: I have to wait 6 more minutes :P

Comment: I didn't know you have to wait, sorry :)